# Neo4j match, Handle either, or, paths, expected case statement

Tags: neo4j

There are two paths `A to D`

`A` to `D` either this can be

```
(A)-[:HAS_B]->(B)-[:HAS_C]->(C)-[:HAS_D]-(D)
```

`or` this can be

```
(A)-[:HAS_C]->(C)-[:HAS_D]-(D)
```

approach 1:working fine, but I don't want, since I need relation Ids, StartId, EndId

```
p= MATCH (a:A)-[*..2]->(c:C)-[:HAS_D]-(d:D) return p
```

approach 2, working fine. needed optimization

```
MATCH (a:A)
OPTIONAL MATCH(a)-[:HAS_B]-(b1:B)
OPTIONAL MATCH(b1)-[:HAS_C]-(c1:C)
OPTIONAL MATCH(c1)-[:HAS_D]-(d1:D)

OPTIONAL MATCH(a)-[:HAS_C]-(c2:C) // this is what I dont want c2
OPTIONAL MATCH(c2)-[:HAS_D]-(d2:D) // this is expanding , manage d1 and d2

WITH collect(DISTINCT id(a))
 + collect(DISTINCT id(b1))
 + collect(DISTINCT id(c1))
 + collect(DISTINCT id(d1))
 + collect(DISTINCT id(c2))
 + collect(DISTINCT id(d2))

    as all_nodes
CALL apoc.algo.cover(all_nodes)
YIELD rel 
RETURN  startNode(rel) as sn, rel, endNode(rel) as en
```

How can I skip `c2`,`d2` case, because it is either or case.
because in real scenario it is not a small graph, I need to handle many `d1` and `d2` scenarios, it is growing.

How can optimize this query with something like `CASE statement`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing a table scan so when the graph grows, your query will start to slow down. Graphs are not meant to be fast of this test case on scanning the entire database.

Comment: @jose_bacoy, I am building dynamic cypher generation, have applied filters in real use case